# ubuntu 22.04.1 network keeps failing - please help!

Tags: networking

I have a problem with my machine and I would appreciate any help! Here's what happened:

1. Recently ran updates on the system
2. I am connected to the internet via an ethernet cable
3. Since the update, the ethernet connection randomly stops working after a certain amount of time. Can be 5 mintues, or a few hours, but it fails.
4. NOTHING works to bring it back (tried everything) BUT rebooting the computer fixes the problem every time.

Since rebooting the computer fixes the problem, it confirms that this is some issue with the os configuration I could fix, right?

Do you have any ideas? I checked everything online and tried ALL the solutions I could find with no luck.

I'd appreciate any help you could give me!

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.